# Subdividing reference list by years

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I want to set up a reference list which is automatically subdividing my publications by structuring the citations by year as title.

Like:

**2014**

Publication 1

Publication 2

**2013**

Publication 1

Publication 2

Publication 3

**2012**

....

....

So far I use (MWE without implemented feature):

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[locale=US]{siunitx}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should take a look at the documentation, `[Usage Notes]`, `Subdivided Bibiographies` (§ 3.11.4, pp. 109–111). You should  use is several commands like `\printbibliography[year=2014]`.